# Is there simple way to display uploaded files as pdf, xml, .xlsx in spring boot-thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, file-upload, thymeleaf

I uploaded files in static resources and I'm displaying them on the page like I would display any picture.

```
<div th:each="tempFile:${files}" class="col-2 mb-4">
     <a th:href="@{'/user/file/' + ${tempFile.idFile}}">
         <img th:src="@{'/files/'+${tempFile.fileName}}" alt="img">
     </a>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to display files that are not images. I would like to display an icon at least if the file isn't an image (pdf icon for pdf extension).
I suppose it is possible with JavaScript but I'm just starting to learn him.

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: any relate to spring boot ?

Comment: @muhammedozbilici It is a Spring Boot application, so yes. Maybe someone can suggest a solution on the backend, to modify the method and not in the HTML, but I'm doing this for the first time, so I'm not sure. That's why I'm here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of brainstorming, I decided to use the `strings.endsWith` method in the conditions and put file extension as a suffix.